# Testing range for WLAN IEEE 802 11b/g/n

Tags: esp32, testing

Are there any standardised test standards to test the Wifi Range of my ESP32 inside of my products enclosure. I want to know what range(s) it can operate so I can provide recommendations to users of my product.

Comment: it depends on the AP as much, maybe more than the MCU.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any standardized test for ESP32 but I found these links which will surely guide you and help you to check the ESP32 signal strength and range.

**1.[ESPressif production testing guide](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/production_testing_guide__EN.pdf)**:

You should read this testing guide which is officially provided by the ESPressif (owner and manufactures of ESPxxx chips).

In this, they have stated the PC testing tool to test the product and everything.
I can't post specific things from this so...Please read it.

**2.According to these**[ESP32 / 8266 WiFi Signal Strength](https://www.instructables.com/id/ESP32-8266-WiFi-Signal-Strength/)**:**

Use WiFi Analyzer which is an application that finds WiFi networks available around us. It also shows the signal strength in dBm and the channel for each network. We will use it to do our analysis, which is possible through visualization in the modes: list or graph.

PHOTO APP --- The app can be downloaded from the Google Play Store through the link:

[Wi-Fi Analyser App Link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.farproc.wifi.analyzer&hl=en)

After downloading the app create an access point in your ESP32 (Which is already done by you I guess) and connect your mobile with ESP32 Wi-Fi and open the App.

You will get a signal graph like this:

> [image]

**1.** check the graph generated according to the intensity of the signal, both near the chips and in a more remote environment with walls in the way.

> **2.** Close to chips - 1 meter. In the above image the first notes of the application. The best performances were from ESP02 and ESP32.

Moving away from the device 15 meters you will get a graph like:

> [image]
>
> In this second stage, the highlight again is the ESP02, which has an
>   external antenna of its own.

**3. According to these**[ESP8266 Range Test with and without External Antenna](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KYLN9qH0C84)**:**

You have to connect any device to the ESP32 inside of your product enclosure and measure the distance according to the connectivity and signal strength of the Wi-Fi.

This link is the ".cpp" code for testing the ESP32[ESP32RangeTest-Slave.cpp](https://gist.github.com/yaqwsx/ac662c9b600ef39a802da0be1b25d32d). There was no guide or any document regarding it so...

Comment: Please post the relevant parts from those links here.  Posts consisting purely of links are not very helpful and are likely to be deleted.

Comment: @Chenmunka I have posted the relevant parts of those links and also The official guide OP has to read to get a fuller understanding of the testing and tools from that I can't take out relevant there is too much content in that.

Comment: Please make sure any text and images you have taken from those sources is shown as quotes (use the quote button in the edit toolbar or add > at the beginning of the relevant lines). They should appear on a yellowish background.

Comment: Upvoted for an excellent answer. Welcome on board, Lucifer